# How to get the directory location of an application file using only the name of the application?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am writing a code in python where the user could enter the name of the application installed in their PC and my program should show the directory location of that application.

I have used  "winapps.search_installed"  to do the same. It showed the location of some of the application, but it didn't showed the location of many applications. My code was like this

```
for item in winapps.search_installed('Epic Games Launcher'):
    location=item.install_location
    print(location)
```

Here as an example I used the Epic games launcher.

Is there any efficient method other than this?

Comment: Is this trying to reinvent `where <application>`?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to make something similar to that

Comment: In that case you will have to start by getting a clear picture on *what* you actually want to accomplish. Windows has multiple ways to install programs, and the locations for those programs are stored in multiple catalogs. Unless you *precisely* define what you need, there's not much we can do to help.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can use `where` in your command line. For example:

```
 where notepad
```

You can use `os.system('where notepad')` to run it from your python code.

Comment: But using this "where",  I can only get the location of the inbuilt system applications. I also need to get the location of external installed applications.

Comment: Uh, no, it will search your `PATH`. If the application is not in your `PATH`, though, this is arguably the wrong approach.